# how to install tailwindcss in react js

Tags: jquery, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am new for react js and tailwind components.

I successfully install react in my page. Its working fine.

But I want install tailwind css for old npm, node version like as

```
{ node: 'v10.15.3', npm: '7.23.0' }
```

I trying to create tailwind config file but i got error like below

```
NPM\myapp>npx tailwindcss init
(node:72880) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental
C:\Users\EXQ504\NPM\myapp\node_modules\@tailwindcss\postcss7-compat\node_modules\color\index.js:257
                        lum[i] = (chan <= 0.039_28) ? chan / 12.92 : ((chan + 0.055) / 1.055) ** 2.4;
                                          ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at new Script (vm.js:80:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:274:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:326:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:664:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
```

I searched some long time but I didn't found good answer in my search criteria.
Any one can help ... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tailwind requires node 12.13+

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation

please upgrade your node version

Comment: I want to install tailwind css in node v10.15.3 version only.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do that. bcz the document clearly mentions it should be 12.13+

Answer (score 1):

Install Tailwind CSS via npm
follow steps are mentioned on website
website url :https://www.ordinarycoders.com/blog/article/reactjs-tailwindcss

Comment: I have follow up that same steps, but I got error like above

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

open cmd in your project folder and enter below command: 
`npm install -D tailwindcss` 
then, enter `npx tailwindcss init` command if you want to create tailwindcss `config` file.

for more details you can refer, https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation